SpeechToText (Voice Recognition) result is empty string on Android device but not on Windows .NET MAUI
Can anyone solve or explain this problem.
Voice Recognition result is ok on Windows but return empty string on Android devices.
Is there possible some permission problem or what else might cause this kind of error.
SpeechToText.RequestPermissions will pass without any errors or problems.
private async Task Listen()
{
    var isGranted = await SpeechToText.RequestPermissions(CancellationToken.None);
    if (!isGranted)
    {
        await Toast.Make("Permission for voice control not granted").Show(CancellationToken.None);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        SpeechToText.Default.StateChanged += Default_StateChanged;
        SpeechToText.Default.RecognitionResultUpdated += Default_RecognitionResultUpdated;
        SpeechToText.Default.RecognitionResultCompleted += Default_RecognitionResultCompleted;
        await SpeechToText.Default.StartListenAsync(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
    }
}

private void Default_StateChanged(object? sender, SpeechToTextStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.State == SpeechToTextState.Stopped)
    {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(SetVoiceControlOff);
    }
}
private void Default_RecognitionResultCompleted(object? sender, SpeechToTextRecognitionResultCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(SetVoiceControlOff);
}

private void Default_RecognitionResultUpdated(object? sender, SpeechToTextRecognitionResultUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Result is ok on Windows but empty string on Android devices

    RecognitionResult = e.RecognitionResult.ToLower();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RecognitionResult))
    {
        //Some code
    }
    else
    {
        //Some code
    }
}


Is there any log about this problem?

Jessie Zhang - Not any log.

How can we reproduce this problem on our side? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem and a Minimal, Reproducible Example so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?
